# Joi - reference value of same object

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I need to reference a previous property (`propertyValue`) to get a max value for another property (`loan`). Currently I've tried:

```js
const products = joi.object().keys({
  propertyValue: joi
    .number()
    .min(40000)
    .required(),
  loan: joi
    .number()
    .min(1)
    .max(joi.ref('propertyValue') - 1)
});
```

But I get the following error: `Error: limit must be a number or reference`

And:

```js
joi.object().keys({
  propertyValue: joi
    .number()
    .min(40000)
    .required(),
  loan: joi
    .number()
    .min(1)
    .max(joi.template('{propertyValue - 1}'))
    .required(),
})
```

Which gives the error: `Not a valid joi Schema`

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [adjust](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#refkey-options) option

```
Joi.object({
  propertyValue: Joi
    .number()
    .min(40000)
    .required(),
  loan: Joi
    .number()
    .min(1)
    .max(Joi.ref('propertyValue', {
      adjust: value => {
        return value - 1;
      }
    }))
    .required()
})
```

**[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-vvsosy?file=index.js)**